# Access to ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/ denied

Tags: security, filesystem, mojave

Since installing Mojave, I can no longer access `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/`:

```
pse@Mithos:~$ ll ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/
ls: DataVaults: Operation not permitted
```

I've granted Full Access to Terminal in System Preferences, nevertheless the error message remains.

What makes this directory so special and how can I get access?

Comment: did you restart after granting ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 No. But access to other directories beneath ~/Library works without issues, even those which haven't been accessible before granting Full Access to Terminal.

Comment: Terminal.app isn't performing the access.  Your shell is.  Your system is working as designed.

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm sure it works that way. But according to that design the Full Access rights given to Terminal get propagated to all binaries run from within Terminal, including the shell. So something else is preventing access here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataVaults directory has to do with [entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html). Access is prevented unless the owner of the entitlement grants the access. The entitlements for Mail.app can be listed as follows and provides an XML plist.

```
codesign -d --entitlements - /Applications/Mail.app/
```

At this time, the only other method to acquire access to the directory is to turn off SIP.

For more details on DataVaults see [No Entry ⛔️: access controls in Mojave](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/10/25/no-entry-%E2%9B%94%EF%B8%8F-access-controls-in-mojave/). The section on DataVaults starts off with

> Introduced in later releases of High Sierra, and used more in Mojave, are folders to which only Apple’s software has even read access, DataVaults. My account here is largely based on comments generously provided here by an anonymous source, as these don’t appear to have been mentioned anywhere by Apple (not even at WWDC 2018), nor can I find other descriptions.

so it all seems to be kind of mystery still.

At some point, Mail.app moved to `/System/Applications/Mail.app`.

Comment: Hmm, I see the entitlements for Mail.app, but where is the definition which prevents access by default?

Comment: Even with "full disc access" configured, apps cannot access `rootless_mkdir`  directories (a.k.a DataVaults) made by the app.

Comment: LOL, googling `rootless_mkdir` just got me [this](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2018/09/10/mojaves-new-security-and-privacy-protections-face-usability-challenges/) which includes your (I assume) tweet on this. Is there anything in Apples documentation explaining this (didn't find it in the link from your answer)?

Comment: No I don't tweet. No, I could not find anything either. I have ordered a copy of OS Internals to see what more I can learn, though. http://newosxbook.com/

Comment: I tried this, in March, 2023, and I get an error message. While I can see Mail in the /Applications folder, when I try accessing it from the command line, it's as if it's not there. And the .app prefix is gone from the packages in /Applications.

Comment: @Tango Mail.app is now `/System/Applications/Mail.app`